# Find out which Python executable QGIS is using on Mac OS

Tags: qgis, python, mac

I'm trying to find the path to the Python executable QGIS 3.6 is using on Mac OS. Usually (i.e. Python "outside" of QGIS) I'd:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

But that only gives me the path to QGIS:

```
/Applications/QGIS3.6.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
```

Is there any straightforward way to find this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the information 'leaked' if I caused an error from the QGIS Python console...

```
print(__dict__)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__dict__' is not defined
```

I see you're on a Mac. I'm pretty sure that Mac QGIS requires the use of the 'standard' python3 framework (i.e. not a Brew version) so it should match the output of `which python3`

I think you can also work it out from the environment

```
import os; print(os.environ["PATH"])
```