# How do I specify the QGIS specific Python version to add Python packages to that version?

Tags: qgis, python, enmap-box

On my MacBook (running Mojave), I have preexisting Python versions (Anaconda and the Python 2.7 that comes with the Mac). I installed QGIS version 3.10.5-A Coruña. To use a QGIS plug-in (Enmap-Box), I need to add some Python packages. My Mac terminal window doesn't recognize the QGIS Python. What do I need to do to switch to the QGIS Python so that I can add packages there?

Answer (score 4):

Open the Python console in QGIS and type `sys.executable`, this will provide you the path to the relevant Python interpreter.

However, for those using Windows, `sys.executable` returns the path to the QGIS application (see issue: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/45646). I used following workaround to install `geojson`. Tested using Linux and Windows with QGIS 3.20.

```py
import os
import sys
import subprocess

def find_python():

    if sys.platform != "win32":
        return sys.executable

    for path in sys.path:  # searching sys.path for python executables
        assumed_path = os.path.join(path, "python.exe")
        if os.path.isfile(assumed_path):
            return assumed_path

    raise Exception("Python executable not found")

python_exe = find_python()
subprocess.check_call([python_exe, "-m", "pip", "install", "geojson"])
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the path to the python executable qgis is using. See this answer: [Find out which Python executable QGIS is using on Mac OS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314942/find-out-which-python-executable-qgis-is-using-on-mac-os) for how you can do that. For our example let us assume that the path to the python executable is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python`. You can then open a terminal and cd to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin`. Then you can run `./python -m pip install [library-you-need-to-install]`. Be careful though. Based on the path it seems that QGIS on Mac uses a system wide python version. If that is the case you might break other applications on your mac if you install python packages. I'm on Windows so I'm not sure the above paths are the right ones.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think QGIS is using the python version indicated by "which python".  I go to the directory hosting that version and am able to successfully import the packages with Enmap Box requires (i.e., I had previously installed them) which leads me to think that QGIS is looking for some other version (since in trying to install the Enmap Box plug-in, QGIS indicated I was missing necessary packages.

Comment: @wfarrand: Don't use `which python`. Start QGIS and write something in the python console that gives an error. E.g. `print(__dict__)` and look at the error message. In the other question I linked to, the error contained `File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/code.py"`. That path gives a hint to where the python version QGIS is using is located

Comment: Great... that worked for finding the QGIS installation of Python. I guess I'm still unclear how to force the local terminal window to use a program such as pip to install packages to THAT version of Python...