# pip install inside QGIS fails

Tags: qgis, import, pyshp, pip

As I am trying to import a pip module directly in the built-in python I need to install pyshp first. I am trying this directly inside qgis running

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'pyshp'])
```

Unfortunately the import stalls on my macOS QGIS version and opens up another QGIS instance. Once I close the unwanted new instance the install fails with the following message:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Collecting pyshp
  Using cached pyshp-2.1.3.tar.gz (219 kB)
ERROR: Files/directories not found in /private/var/folders/ds/0mbtck497x300z6gxgt1bs3h0000gr/T/pip-install-lfa5pmvg/pyshp/pip-egg-info
1
```

Can anyone provide some insight or even a fix?
A similar pip install with flask or others went fine with some warnings.

I would also be happy to run a pip install outside of the wrapped python in QGIS but I have some troubles finding the right python version on my system (I have plenty due to anaconda and other python-tools).

Answer (score 4):

I circled around the problem by calling the correct python version directly in the terminal and ran:

```
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/python3.8 -m pip install pyshp
```

The command

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

pointed me to

```
'/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS'
```

and after I explored the content of the path I found the python3.8 command. Until now I was not able to install it via the interpreter inside QGIS itself.

Answer (score 3):

You're not supposed to call `pip` from python, because reasons you can read about here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program

The solution, which seems to work in QGIS, is given there and is:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'my_package'])
```

Note that `pip` output goes to QGIS' standard output stream, and **not** to the Python console window, so might not be visible if you run it from double-clicking an icon. When run from a Linux command terminal, I see `pip` output there. It is also the place where `pip` asks questions and expects input, so you may have to run QGIS from a command-line interface, or make sure you have any other options in the subprocess call so that `pip` doesn't have to ask anything.

Also, if you are ever having trouble finding out which Python exe is being run, `import sys` and `sys.executable` should be the path (as used in the code above).

Comment: thanks for the hint. at least on MAC sys.executable is not pointing to the right python executable. On my system (running 3.16.15 LTR) it shows:
sys.executable
'/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS'

Comment: Hmmm. I get `/usr/bin/python3` on my Linux box from the QGIS console Python...

Comment: Does this work? https://gist.github.com/moosetraveller/a5b2117db5a9207bcfedf2927d127ce2

Comment: nope! throws a "None"

Comment: It is a general problem with embedded python interpreters under Windows that `sys.executable` does not behave like described in the official documentation. I opened an issue quite a while ago: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/45646. Also just updated the gist page @Spacedman has provided. Also maybe this question may help you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/361545/21355